# while bootstrapping a recipe on windows machine ..facing issues like ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired

Tags: knife, chef-infra

When I am bootstrapping a recipe on windows machine. I am facing an error which is shown below:

**$ knife bootstrap windows winrm  IP-address -x Username -P password -r recipe[notepad]**

**ERROR: HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired**

I have installed knife windows pluggin and also configured the winrm but after doing this also .. I am facing this issue.

I could not resolve this. Has anyone come across this problem and found a solution?

Comment: atually .. i got the solution for the issue   
in this path   /etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb   
Add the following content below
bookshelf['url'] = "https://<IP address>:443"

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually .. i got the solution for the issue in this path /etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb .  Add the following content below bookshelf['url'] = "https://:443"