# ERROR: HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError: execution expired while bootsrapping using knife

Tags: windows, chef-infra, knife

I am on a windows machine and trying to bootstrap a windows server 2012 and facing the same issues as mentioned in the below question. Any help regarding this?

[while bootstrapping a recipe on windows machine ..facing issues like ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987688/while-bootstrapping-a-recipe-on-windows-machine-facing-issues-like-connecttime)

Comment: Hey could you please provide more detail which chef version you are using?

Comment: Chef Workstation version: 1.0.11
Chef Infra Client version: 15.2.20
Chef InSpec version: 4.10.4
Test Kitchen version: 2.2.5
Foodcritic version: 16.1.1
Cookstyle version: 0.72.0